# Toggle CSS Transform Button For All Elements with the * Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Been trying to solve this all day, but just can't work it out. It's probably something really simple, but nothing seems to work.

I am using Divi scroll animations. However, on some devices they are a bit too much, so I made a button that switched them off, by disabling transform globally. However, I also want to be able to turn it back on again. I tried `toggle`, but it didn't work.

Because I'm not targeting a style, I can't use class toggles etc. It probably needs to be a style toggle, but on the `*`. So I was wonder if there is a way of doing this; or even better, how can this can be done without Jquery?

This is the [site](https://blockyouth.org/) I'm trying to get it to work on.

Any solutions, are really appreciated.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#turnOffNow").click(function(){
    $("*").css("transform", "none");
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="turnOffNow" style="color:#fff;">
  Turn Off Animations
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem.

Add a class to your CSS:

```css
.notransform * {
    transform: none;
}
```

Append this class to your html tag in your page:

```js
$("#turnOffNow").click(function(){
    $("html").toggleClass("notransform");
});
```

You can also try `transform: none !important` to force that.

Comment: +1 because your answer is valid, but it would be helpful to explain why this is the case, as this will help @InvariantChange from coming across similar errors in the future

Comment: I can work out why from the answer. It's using the notransform class to call the all selector, then I can use that to toggle the class. Can't believe I missed that one. Super simple.

I guess, I'll now just convert this method in to vanilla JS to avoid calling another jQuery js file. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for be able to turn it on, assuming you has some inline transforms which was gone, better you give them `css class`, which will give them `transform:none !important` then remove it for turn on.

example css:

```
body.no-transform * {transform: none !important}
```

js (jQuery)

```
function removeTransform(){$('body').addClass("no-transform")}
function backTransform(){$('body').removeClass("no-transform")}
```

js (Vanilla)

```
function removeTransform(){document.body.classList.add("no-transform")}
function backTransform(){document.body.classList.remove("no-transform")}
```